# выводить случайные числа в pygame

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

как заставить pygame выводить случайные числа? конечно цель преследуется другая но хотелось бы понять на этом примере.

```
import pygame 
from pygame.locals import * 

pygame.init()
getSize = pygame.display.Info()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((getSize.current_w, getSize.current_h))#, pygame.FULLSCREEN)

w = getSize.current_w
h = getSize.current_h

pygame.display.set_caption('');
fontSize = 20
myFont = pygame.font.SysFont('Calibri', fontSize)
fontColor = (255,255,255)
bgColor = (0,0,0)
text = 'blablabla'
fontImage = myFont.render(str(text), 9, (fontColor))
mainLoop = True
while mainLoop:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            mainLoop = False
    screen.fill(bgColor)
    screen.blit(fontImage, (w / 2 - 50, h / 2))
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

скажем так - как соединить эти два куска кода? не могу разобраться

```
import random
import time

a = random.randrange(1, 100)
while a > 0:
    print(a)
    time.sleep(1)
    a = random.randrange(1, 100)
```

Comment: Точно так же, как и любой другой текст.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала проинициализируйте pygame.font, а затем отрендерите

```
pygame.font.init() #1
labelFont = pygame.font.SysFont('Monaco', 30)
rendersurface = labelFont.render('your text or number', False, (0, 0, 0))
screen.blit(labelFont, (0, 0))
```

Засуньте последние два действия в цикл и вместо текста подставляйте случайное число.

R1: Если вы уже вызвали

```
pygame.init()
```

, то не нужно добавлять первую строчку.